# Error when adding ReportViewer to Toolbox

Tags: .net, winforms, reportviewer

I did everything from the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhcg4dy43xk). Added Miscosoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.v12 to NuGet, rebuilt, dragged ReportViewer from Toolbox and it gives an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWjkv.png

The localization is in Russian. If you need, I can translate it. Are there any options how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

While English message would have helped, it appears you are missing Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common reference. Try adding this package as well and ensure you are using the right version.